# Save excursion not working for dired-find-file-other-window

Tags: dired, save-excursion, selected-window

I wrote this function to basically bring my cursor back to the `dired` buffer, after opening the file in another window.  This is so that I can scroll down the buffer, pressing `o` to keep previewing the files in the directory. However, after the function is called, my cursor just stays at the other window, where the file has been opened.

```
 (defun tian-emacs-macros/dired-find-file-other-window ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (dired-find-file-other-window)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to write a custom function this time. You're looking for `dired-display-file`, bound to `C-o`.